# Aggregating Firebase Stream in Flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I am trying to Aggregate a number field from multiple documents in firebase.

I am wanting to set an aggregate amount in the App Bar.
I have tried a few different things and haven't been able to get it to work. 
I do know that my totalizer method is working as expected. 
I have been trying to save it off into a global variable and then setting that in the App Bar.
I do want it to be recalculated on any update to the database.
Any ideas on  a better way/or even working way to do this would be appreciated.

Thanks

This is my latest attempt at it:

```
          StreamBuilder(
               stream: transactions,
               builder: (context, snapshot) {
               total = total + totalizer(snapshot.data.documents[0]);
               )
```

Comment: I may be way off on trying to use a stream builder on this also. I haven't been able to find any documentation on this issue anywhere so any help would be great.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A running sum or a sum at the end after all events were received?

Comment: Perhaps you want to move the business logic (aggregation) into the stream itself.  There are stream processors, such as [reduce](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Stream/reduce.html) that will let you aggregate.  It returns a Future, but you can use `.asStream()`.  If you move the stream to its own class, you're on your way to [BLoC](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/08/reactive-programming---streams---bloc/)

Comment: Gunter, I am hoping to have a running sum or sum at the end which is updated every time the database is updated. I think the key point is that i want it to be dynamic as the loads on the list view for the items I am populating are also. I have tried updating var on the loop through the stream in the item builder and also tried wrapping the stream in method and calling it on the title in the app bar and neither have executed and have broken the loop. James thank you for the articles and the ideas I am definitely going to check them out in depth and try to apply the techniques that they show.